# How to fetch CONVERSION EVENTS list through GA4 API

Tags: events, google-analytics-4

Passed post parameters as **DIMENSION : "isConversionEvent"** , **METRICS : "conversions", "totalUsers", "totalRevenue"**

However, the response result doesn't match with the GA4 native dashboard data.

Post Parameters:

```
{
"dimensions" : [
    {
        "name" : "isConversionEvent"
    }
],
"metrics" : [
    {
        "name": "eventCount"
    },
    {
        "name": "conversions"
    },
    {
        "name": "totalUsers"
    },
    {
        "name": "totalRevenue"
    }
],
"date_ranges": [
        {
            "start_date": "2023-06-07",
            "end_date": "2023-07-04"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response Data :

```
{
"dimensionHeaders": [
    {
        "name": "isConversionEvent"
    }
],
"metricHeaders": [
    {
        "name": "eventCount",
        "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "name": "conversions",
        "type": "TYPE_FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "name": "totalUsers",
        "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "name": "totalRevenue",
        "type": "TYPE_CURRENCY"
    }
],
"rows": [
    {
        "dimensionValues": [
            {
                "value": "(not set)"
            }
        ],
        "metricValues": [
            {
                "value": "33788"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "value": "4212"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dimensionValues": [
            {
                "value": "true"
            }
        ],
        "metricValues": [
            {
                "value": "207"
            },
            {
                "value": "207"
            },
            {
                "value": "115"
            },
            {
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"rowCount": 2,
"metadata": {
    "schemaRestrictionResponse": {},
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "timeZone": "America/New_York"
},
"kind": "analyticsData#runReport"
}
```

GA4 native dashboard data for reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JObQ.png)

Can you please suggest/guide how can we get conversion events list data through GA4 API?

Post Parameters:

[image]

Expected Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm4bm.png)